# alter command in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter

I am trying to alter a view by adding a new column to the existing view for which i need a temporary table created.

now i am not able to create temp table as it says that

```
 'ALTER VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.
```

My Code snippet looks like

```
 declare @temp_table table (x int,y xml,z int)
   insert into @temp_table (x,y,z)
      select(t.loc.value('(text()[1])','nvarchar(max)') from table1 
      Cross Apply ExtensionData.nodes('/xml/xml')  AS  t(Loc)
      where t.loc.value(@id,smallint)=1)

 Alter dbo.myview
  as 
  select
   existingcolumns,
   newcolumn from 
   existing_table et left join 
   temp_table tt on et.x=tt.x
```

Please advise what can be done best. I have the idea of dropping the view and recreating it, but ideally that is not the best way to go.

Comment: Put a `; go` on the line before the view.

Comment: Why do you need the table variable created? You can't reference it in a view if that's the intention. Probably need a multistatement TVF.

Comment: I don't think that you can use a temporary table in a view, since the view lives longer than the temporary table. See this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx It says that "The SELECT clauses in a view definition cannot include the following: (...) A reference to a temporary table or a table variable."

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can use a temporary table in a view, since the view lives longer than the temporary table.

In [the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx), it says that "The SELECT clauses in a view definition cannot include the following: (...) A reference to a temporary table or a table variable."

Answer (score 0):

You need a `GO` :

```
declare @temp_table table (x int,y xml,z int)
   insert into @temp_table (x,y,z)
      select(t.loc.value('(text()[1])','nvarchar(max)') from table1 
      Cross Apply ExtensionData.nodes('/xml/xml')  AS  t(Loc)
      where t.loc.value(@id,smallint)=1)

GO

 Alter dbo.myview
  as 
  select
   existingcolumns,
   newcolumn from 
   existing_table et left join 
   temp_table tt on et.x=tt.x
```

Comment: Is a variable still available after go?

Comment: I am getting a new error now...

              Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Procedure myview, Line 51
Must declare the table variable "@temp".